# Akka stream, upstream not producing values

Tags: kotlin, akka-stream

I have an Akka stream that I want to use to start a session against a 3rd party API and then I want it to keep that session alive by emitting keepAlive requests on a set interval.

Now I've managed to collect the first session signature element from the stream by collecting it to a SinkQueue but I cannot seem to get upstream to keep producing elements, this is my code:

```
 val signatures = Source.single({ _: String ->
        sessionManager.logon(logonReq, contractVersion).signature
    }).keepAlive(interval, {{ signature: String ->
        sessionManager.keepAlive(KeepAliveRequest(), contractVersion, signature)
        signature
    }})

fun start() = signatures.
        conflateWithSeed({ it("") } ,{ x, f -> f(x) }).
        runWith(Sink.queue<String>().withAttributes(Attributes.inputBuffer(0, 1)), mat)
```